# After writing into a file with java the file isn't usable for further processing

Tags: java, perl

I write with a java program into a file for further processing. This is the code for writing into the file:

```
FileOutputStream fos;
File f = new File(outputFilePath);
fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

final String R = "\r";

try {
    fos.write((outputString + R).getBytes());
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("fail..."+ e);
}
```

This works fine and after process I check with notepad++ the file and the right lines are in it. But if I want to use it with a perlscript (obj2opengl.pl) there comes an error. If I copy exactly that text into a new textfile manually with notepad++ it works. So my assumption is that there is somesthing wrong or bad in my java code. I tried already other encodings and so on... maybe anyone have an idea.

The error of the perl script says: "Illegal division by zero at obj2opengl.pl line 294".

That error not occured if I test it with the same text after copied it in a new textfile.

Comment: Can you share your Perl code which reads the file?

Comment: Hi Chankey Pathak, the perl script is here: https://github.com/HBehrens/obj2opengl/blob/master/obj2opengl.pl

Comment: In line 294 of script it's trying to do division operation `$scalefac = 1.0 / $scalefac;` so my guess is that there `$scalefac` is evaluating to `0` which gives an error of `illegal division by zero`.

Comment: thank you for your help but Sheldon answer already solved my problem

Comment: yes. The script is taking values based on lines (for which \n is needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
final String R = "\r";
```

to

```
final String R = "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call close too FileOutputStream object:

```
fos.close();
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot this. But this don't fix my problem. Thanks